# Change chkconfig used by Centos 6.3 to print "on" in bright green (like Ubuntu's chkconfig)?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, chkconfig

`chkconfig` on Ubuntu will highlight services that are **on** in green when using list mode.

[image]

This does not occur on CentOS 6.3.  I'd like that highlighting on the CentOS `chkconfig`.  Does anyone know how to do that?

#### Man entry on Ubuntu describing green highlighting

```
root@console:~# man chkconfig | grep -C 2 "green"
```

> LIST MODE
>
> List  mode  prints for each specified service a line that consists of
>   the service name and for runlevels zero to six on or off depending if
>   the service will be started or not.  on will be printed in bright
>   green if the output is written to a terminal. If the --deps option is
>   given, the names of the services that must be started before this
>   service is appended to each line. The inetd/xinetd services are listed
>   in extra sections.

#### Centos 6.3 chkconfig package info

```
[root@centos:/]$ rpm -qa | grep "chkconfig"
chkconfig-1.3.49.3-2.el6.x86_64
```

#### Debian chkconfig package info

```
root@ubuntu:~# dpkg -s chkconfig
Package: chkconfig
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 68
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Version: 11.0-79.1-2
Depends: perl
Recommends: insserv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always just do it yourself. For example, add this to your `~/.bashrc` (easy enough to modify for other shells):

```
alias chkconfig="chkconfig | perl -pe 'use Term::ANSIColor; s/\bon\b/color(\"green\").on.color(\"reset\")/ige;'"
```

If you want to be able to pass arguments to `chkconfig` use a function instead:

```
function chkconfig(){
   /sbin/chkconfig $* | perl -pe 'use Term::ANSIColor; s/\bon\b/color("green").on.color("reset")/ige;'
}
```

Comment: This didn't work: http://imgur.com/2b7ahXc

Comment: @brakertech it will if you don't run it with `--list` (which is not a valid option anyway).

Comment: @brakertech see updated answer for a way to pass arguments to chkconfig

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
chkconfig --list | grep --color '.:on'
```

Create a wrapper script or an alias with the line above to call it directly.

Comment: That will only print the lines that match `on`. In fact, on my system it will print nothing because `--list` is not a valid option and anyway, no lines match '.:on'

Comment: on my machine it highlights "on" in red instead of green

Comment: Run just chkconfig command without --list switch. It should print the same.